# RCloud load multiple notebooks from files (.gists)

Tags: rcloud

Is there a method to import multiple RCloud notebooks at once?  I am currently using the "Advanced" GUI/dropdown menu function "Import Notebook from File" which imports one file (.gists) at a time.

Thank you!

Comment: Hmm, if you're importing from GitHub gists, you can use the Import External Notebooks feature to import them by their IDs from another GitHub server, as long as that server is accessible from the destination server. We don't currently have a way to import multiple notebooks from files, but it's worth considering - please [file an issue](https://github.com/att/rcloud/issues/new) if that sounds helpful.